# How to aproach a presentation of information theory without solid background

Tags: random-generation, information-theory

I study first year of an applied statistics bachelor, in one of my courses i have to do a presentation of information theory and i would like to share with you my ideas about it in order that you could inspire me.

I want it to have two parts, at first i would like to talk about **random extractors** and in the second part i would like to do a simulation of a case for experiment with the theory i presented in the first part.

Where do you think i could find interesting papers about this for get more inspired?, i would thank any kind of reference to papers that could help me with this presentation.

Can i relate this with Shannon entropy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Not relevant as the poster has not been seen for ages